# LogStash search Queries

Tags: logstash

Using logstash i have send the information to the server and now i am trying to query using head plugin. This query is based on some field value which i send earlier to the server but its return me all the records instead of matched records.  I am using _search and GET as a method in head plugin.My query as like below

```
{ 
    "match": {
        "loginid": { 
            "query": "hello",
            "type": "phrase",
            "slop": 1
        }
    }
}
```

But if try do the same by using 
http://localhost:9200/_search?q=UnYO6qGfIxCUwaUZopYbLw  i am getting only matched data. Can you please let me know what i missed in head plug in query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using query_string query rather than match query then. I believe by default q uses query_string query.

Comment: i tried as below but still no luck 
{
  "simple_query_string": {
    "fields": [
      "loginid"
    ],
    "query": "hello"
  }
}

Comment: Not simple_query_string , just query_string

Comment: I tried as below correct me if i am wrong but this is not working
{
  "query_string": {
    "default_field": "loginid",
    "query": "hello"
  }
}

Comment: { "query" : { "query_string": { "default_field": "loginid", "query": "hello" } } }

Comment: Its working only if go for structured query in head plugin but if i use any request tab it always returns all the results not only matched results

Comment: Change GET to POST in the request tab